# Sum result of two consults mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have this query:

```
SELECT nombrelocal, COUNT(*) FROM `resultados` WHERE id_liga = '1235' AND (reslocal + resvisitante) >= 2 AND reslocal != 99 AND resvisitante != 99 GROUP BY nombrelocal
```

Result:

```
nombrelocal         COUNT(*)    
Alaves              10
Athletic             8
Atletico de Madrid   7
```

And I have this other query:

```
SELECT nombrevisitante, COUNT(*) FROM `resultados` WHERE id_liga = '1235' AND (reslocal + resvisitante) >= 2 AND reslocal != 99 AND resvisitante != 99 GROUP BY nombrevisitante
```

Result:

```
nombrelocal         COUNT(*)    
Alaves              7
Athletic            5
Atletico de Madrid  3
```

I would like sum the two querys, I want this result:

```
nombrelocal         COUNT(*)    
Alaves              17
Athletic            13
Atletico de Madrid  10
```

Thank you

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The results of both queries do not seem consistent. I would expect that the sum of `COUNT(*)` should be the same for both queries, since the `WHERE` clause is the same.

Comment: What if there are `nombrelocal`s that are not `nombrevisitante`, or `nombrevisitante`s that are not `nombrelocal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest approach is probably `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT nombre, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT nombrelocal nombre
    FROM `resultados` 
    WHERE id_liga = '1235' AND (reslocal + resvisitante) >= 2 AND reslocal != 99 AND resvisitante != 99 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nombrevisitante nombre
    FROM `resultados` 
    WHERE id_liga = '1235' AND (reslocal + resvisitante) >= 2 AND reslocal != 99 AND resvisitante != 99 
) t
GROUP BY nombre
```

Comment: That is just that I need it. Thank you so much